# Ubuntu : This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I am trying to run the following command after I have downloaded a tar file using the sudo wget command to install CasperJS on our Ubuntu box.

```
sudo tar -xvf casperjs.tar

This does not look like a tar archive
Skipping to next header
Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Do I need to run the original sudo tar command differently?

Comment: What commands/url/file did you use for wget. A downloaded tar is normally compressed like a `.tgz` or `.gz`. (I seldom see an uncompressed `.tar` file online)

Comment: The command was :-
sudo wget -O casperjs.tar https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/tarball/1.0.0

Comment: By the way why do you add `sudo` in front of all commands? From the security point of view you certainly should not run Internet clients (`wget`) as a superuser.

Comment: For future reference: There is a nice command named `file`. If I use `file demo.tgz` I get a `demo.tgz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Nov  8 13:31:16 2013`. Running `file` on a plain tar file returns: 'demo.tar: POSIX tar archive'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to see what you got:

```
file casperjs.tar
```

and then to see its content, if it IS a tar file:

```
tar tvf casperjs.tar
tar tvzf casperjs.tar  #if that was a gzip-ed tar file
tar tvbf casperjs.tar  #if that was a bzip-ed tar file
tar tvZf casperjs.tar  #if that was a compress-ed tar file  #now very unlikely...
 #note that after the 'f', you need to have a SEPARATOR (space, or tab) followed by the FILENAME. 
 #ie, you can't place an option after the f
 #ex: "tar tvfz something.tar.gz", would try to open file "z" instead and find "something.tar.gz" inside it...
```

then change the 't' into 'x' to extract (I recommend to first use 't', though...)

Comment: When I run the command file casperjs.tar it states "Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract"

Comment: @Zabs: I believe Rik tried to download it and found it out to be a gzip'ed tar. If so, it would be : `tar xvzf casperjs.tar`. However, if it really a zip (instead of gzip) file : `mv casperjs.tar casperjs.tar.zip ; unzip casperjs.tar.zip` and then untar the extracted tar file[s].

Answer (score 4):

The file you downloaded was a `.tar.gz`. (A compressed `.tar` file)

You can use

```
tar -zxvf casperjs.tar
```

But actually you should have downloaded it as a `.tgz` like this:

```
sudo wget -O casperjs.tar github.com/n1k0/casperjs/tarball/1.0.0 –O casperjc.tgz
sudo tar -zxvf casperjs.tgz
```

The `-z` stands for:

> -z, --gzip, --ungzip               filter the archive through gzip